# Julia for multivariate analysis - ideal gas law

Tags: indexing

I have values of temperature (temp), pressure (pres) and volume (vol), and I'm trying to check in Julia if the data fits the ideal gas law: PV = nRT. However, I keep getting this error at the line with the curve_fit function: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 2-element Vector{Float64} at index [3]. My code:

```
using LsqFit, Plots

# IDEAL GAS LAW
function ideal_gas_law(params,data)
        T, V, P = data
        n,R = params
        return n*R.*T.-P.*V
end

# DATA AND INITIAL PARAMETERS
temp = [305.15,305.15,307.15,308.25,308.65] # K
vol = [6e-05,5.5e-05,5e-05,4.5e-05,3.5e-05] # m³
pres = [98100.0,109500.0,117600.0,125000.0,144400.0] # N/m²
data_matrix = hcat(temp,vol,pres)
p0 = [1.0, 8.31]

# FITTING
fit_result = curve_fit(ideal_gas_law, data_matrix, pres, p0)
fit_params = fit_result.param
fit_error = estimate_errors(fit_result)

# PLOT
scatter(temp, vol, pres, label="Data", xlabel="Temperature (K)", ylabel="Volume (m³)", zlabel="Pressure (N/m²)", marker=:circle)
plot!(temp, fit_params[1] * fit_params[2] .* temp, label="Fit", c=:red)
savefig("syringe-idealgas.png")
```

I thought at first that the problem was with the data_matrix, but when changing it to a tuple I got a type error instead.